# path env variable doesn't work after log off and log in

Tags: linux, node.js

I just installed nodejs on my RHEL7 box and set my path like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/node/bin 
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/node/lib/node_modules
```

So this works except when I log off and back in, then I have to set it again.

I tried editing ~/.bash_profile with this:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/node/bin:/usr/local/node/lib/node_modules
```

but that didn't work either. How do I set it so I don't have to keep exporting the var?

EDIT:

tried this as well...

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/node/bin" >> /.bash_profile
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/node/lib/node_modules" >> /.bash_profile
source /.bash_profile
```

but that didn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

Use `export` in the `.bash_profile`.

Comment: You write `export` before the variable name. Exactly as you did in the shell in your posted example.

Comment: tried this in bash_profile `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/node/bin:/usr/local/node/lib/node_modules` but that didn't work either...is that right what I'm doing?

Comment: How are you using this shell? If you are using it as an interactive login shell then `.bash_profile` should be working. If you are using it as a subshell or calling it as a script from cron or somewhere, then you should be using `.bashrc` or perhaps `$BASH_ENV` instead, or setting the path in a the script, in the case of a script. See https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html#lbAH